# Where the hash values can be seen in Manifest per file?

Tags: .net, hash, assemblies, clr

This is a citation from Jeffrey Richter's CLR via C# book:

*"When you build a strongly named assembly, the assembly’s
FileDef manifest metadata table includes the list of all the files that make up the assembly.
As each file’s name is added to the manifest, the file’s contents are hashed, and this hash
value is stored along with the file’s name in the FileDef table."*

**Question:**
Can you explain if each file (my understanding is referenced assemblies + resources) is hashed and if the hash value per file is stored within MANIFEST, where/how can I find/see these hash values inside manifest?

When I open the manifest I cannot spot it for a sample assembly I have. I only see Assembly Information under .assembly ConsoleTests {...}

Answer (score 3):

By *all of the files that make up the assembly*, author means `netmodule`s, not referenced assemblies.

If the assembly consists only of its own single file, `FileDef` table will be empty.
You will be able to see the hashes in the manifest if you try to build an assembly that consists of multiple modules. Try this:

(1) Create three source files (for three modules):

```
// module1.cs
namespace MultiModuleAssembly
{
    public class Class1 { }
}

// module2.cs
namespace MultiModuleAssembly
{
    public class Class2 { }
}

// main.cs
namespace MultiModuleAssembly
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1();
            Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        }
    }
}
```

(2) Compile each file into `.netmodule`:

```
csc /t:module module1.cs
csc /t:module module2.cs
csc /t:module main.cs /addmodule:module1.netmodule /addmodule:module2.netmodule
```

(3) Sign the main module with a key:

```
al main.netmodule /keyfile:key.snk /out:main-signed.dll
```

(4) Open `main-signed.dll` in `ildasm`, and double-click the `M A N I F E S T` node:

```
// Somewhere in the middle of the listing
.file main.netmodule
    .hash = (89 84 FB F2 BB 72 AA 13 44 76 A5 49 8F 13 99 3E   // .....r..Dv.I...>
             54 30 24 84 )                                     // T0$.
```